# How to revert the applied patches in magento 2

Tags: magento2, patches, paypal-express

In my root folder, there is a folder named vendor_patches. Inside that, there are some patch files for the Paypal module. But the requirement is like after applying those patches, I need to revert that patches. I have also checked the patch_list table. But no entries were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that we can revert those patches by removing the vendor folder and reinstalling through the composer update command